# Bordered CSS card with cut out in top right

Tags: html, css

I need to have a div with a gray border around the outside of 20px. I also need to have a cut out in the top right of the div. the border in the top left must be the same as the rest of the border, it needs to be 20px. The cut out also needs to be transparent.

here is my best try at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/tybourque/2bZAW/5959/

```
.card-cutout:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: -20px;
 right: -80px;
 border-top: 80px solid transparent;
 border-left: 80px solid #828282;
 width: 0;
 z-index: 10;
}
.card-cutout:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 right: -62px;
 border-top: 65px solid transparent;
 border-left: 62px solid white;
 width: 0;
 z-index: 11;
}
```

any idea on how to easily do this?
[image]

Comment: You should look at pseudo-elements :before and :after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *easily* do this using a `:before` pseudo-element and some gradients:

```css
html, body {
  background: #000;
}

div {
  background: #fff;
  border: 20px solid #aaa;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
}

div:before {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #fff 38%, #aaa 38%, #aaa 56%, #000 57%);
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    top: -20px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks definitely the accepted answer the gradients made the difference. if anyone is looking to know how to do this and have the cutout be transparent look here: https://jsfiddle.net/tybourque/ry6pj7rd/1/